# How should I do a 301 redirect / rewrite on my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I am migrating my WordPress website from a sub-domain to the main domain:

So from `blog.example.net` to `example.net`.

A typical post URL on the sub-domain would be:

```
https://blog.example.net/mypost
```

A typical post on the new domain would be the same:

```
https://example.net/mypost
```

The WordPress permalink settings are the same on both.  If I add this Rewrite rule to my .htaccess file on `blog.example.net`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.net [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

then page is redirected to:

```
https://www.example.net/YYYY/MM/DD/mypost
```

and the page is not found on the new domain:

How do I remove the `/YYYY/MM/DD/` from the URL on `https://example.net/mypost`?

Comment: I have identified the cause of the problem as one existing on the target server's .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if there is a date in URI like `/2018/03/07`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.example.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^   https://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If it is exactly like `YYYY/MM/DD` , replace with this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.example.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[Y]{4}/[M]{2}/[D]{2}/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^   https://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry @Mohammed. This may work but I have identified the cause of the problem as one existing on the target server's .htaccess file.

Comment: paste target server .htacces file

Comment: Sorry @Mohammed. Problem now resolved. Thanks for your help.